# Physics of paintings created by the orbit of swinging buckets filled with paint

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, everyday-life, home-experiment

I am intrigued about the physics behind these [paintings](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DNM8L6UAiPU), which are created by swinging a bucket with a hole filled with paint from a rope ([here](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/om0QsXQBehI) it is another example).

In principle, it seems to be a spherical pendulum, whose lagrangian and equations of motion in spherical coordinates are

$$L=\frac{1}{2} ml^2\left(  \dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta\ \dot{\phi}^2 \right) + mgl\cos\theta \tag{1}$$
$$\ddot\theta=\sin\theta\cos\theta\dot\phi ^2-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta \tag{2}$$
$$\ddot\phi \sin\theta = -2\dot\theta\dot{\phi}\cos\theta \tag{3}$$

I have numerically solved these equations (using a fourth-order Runge-Kutta method) to determine the Cartesian coordinates of the pendulum at various times, trying different combinations of initial values for the positions and the velocities. However, I have not been able to replicate the shapes of the paintings accurately.

[image]

Although the simple pendulum is well known to be independent of the mass, I have tried to modify the lagrangian to account for a time-dependent mass, which results in an extra $-\dot{\theta}\dot{m}/m(t)$ and an extra $-\dot{\phi}\sin(\theta)\dot{m}/m(t)$ term at the RHS of equations (1) and (2), next to next. Despite this modification, the numerical results seem to be independent of the mass.

Could the difference between the shape of the painting and the one of a "pure" spherical pendulum be due to the drag? Could any other factor be affecting the orbit of the bucket?

Comment: It might be that you modeled the pendulum as a point particle instead of a physical pendulum which will have a period that depends on the moment of inertia of a cylindrical bob of variable mass.

Comment: You should add some friction; the videos clearly show the decline of the amplitude after a few cycles. My guess, and it is only a guess, nothing more, that the location of the *effective* friction is at the suspension point.